# How do I see the swagger web interface?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger

I'm trying to visualize my endpoints with swagger but I can't get it to work, my project is done with spring boot, java 20 and maven.

pom.xml:
[image: pom.xml]

This is the path of my controller:

[image: this is the path of my controller]

Web error:

[image: web error]

I want to see my endpoints with the swagger web interface

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try this url: `localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

have you already configured the swagger part?

you need to:

1. setup your swagger
2. @EnableSwagger2 on our configuration class
3. Swagger UI adds a set of resources that we must configure as part of a class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and is annotated with @EnableWebMvc:

To verify it is working try: http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs to have the JSON response

4. to see the Swagger UI you need to enable it:

   io.springfox
        springfox-swagger-ui
        3.0.0

and try http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api